# How can i add icon before shipping method name in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, magento2.2

I want to add Image before Shipping method name in Checkout page.I have checked in shipping.html but here all data coming from js.I can't find proper way for it. Right now i want to add icon for "Flat Rate" shipping method.

Comment: have you tried adding it via css?

Comment: No because i can't find any unique class for each shipping method.

Comment: can you add some code where you want to add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vendor: Vendor
>
> Module: CheckoutStep

**Step - 1:** Override shipping component at **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                Vendor_CheckoutStep/js/view/krish-shipping
             </item>
         </item>
     </item>
 </item>
```

**Step -2:** Create **di.xml** to define our custom object to **checkoutConfig** at

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- pass custom variable to checkout page -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout_custom_shipping_block" xsi:type="object">
                      Vendor\CheckoutStep\Model\CustomConfigProvider
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Create **customConfigProvider** to add media url to checkoutConfig

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CheckoutStep\Model;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );
        $config = [];
        $config['mediaUrl'] = $mediaUrl;
        return $config;
    }
}
```

**Step -4:** Create **krish-shipping.js** at

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/view/frontend/web/js/view/krish-shipping.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        customer,
        Component
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_CheckoutStep/shipping'
            },

            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;
                this._super();

                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()){
                    self.visible(false);
                }
            },

            getMediaUrl: function(methodCode) {
                var imageurl = window.checkoutConfig.mediaUrl + methodCode + '.png';
                return imageurl;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**Step-5:** Copy **shipping.html** from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

**To**

> app/code/Vendor/CheckoutStep/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Add image tag in shipping method foreach loop

```
<!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->

<td class="col col-carrier">
       <img data-bind="attr: {
              'src': $parent.getMediaUrl(method.method_code)
         }" width="50"/>
</td>
```

Now copy shipping images like **flatrate.png** or **bestway.png** with method name in pub/media folder.

You can also customize like create new field in admin and change image via admin via customConfigProvider model file.

Comment: Hello @Prince Patel when I change the country its reflect to shipping methods section and then logo disappear. I debug and see that in the consol that there will be another json response in which my logo is not available. Where will this json prepare?

Comment: I have error in json response